# Magento 2 sales report missing 4 days

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, sales, reports

My Magento 2 sales report has just randomly missed 4 days out this month (17th,18th,19th,20th) Even though there is sales data for them days, all in processing just like the other days. There is nothing different about the days. Has anyone had this issue? i have re-indexed, refreshed statistics all the usual stuff.

[image]